# How to create multiple records in Odoo v16

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16

I'm trying to create multiple records (planning.slot) odoo (V16) in python.
I create this method :

```
@api.model_create_multi
def create(self, vals_list):
    new_vals_list = []

    for vals in vals_list:
        employee_ids = vals.get('employee_ids', [])
        resource_ids = vals.get('resource_ids', [])

        if self.env.context.get('new_button_slot') and employee_ids:
            for list_employee_id in employee_ids:
                if len(list_employee_id) > 1:
                    for data_employe_id in list_employee_id[2]:
                        employe_id = self.env['hr.employee'].browse(data_employe_id)
                        if employe_id:
                            new_vals = vals.copy()
                            new_vals['resource_id'] = employe_id.resource_id.id
                            new_vals['employee_ids'] = False
                            new_vals['resource_ids'] = False
                            new_vals_list.append(new_vals)
    
    return  super(PlanningSlot, self).create(new_vals_list)
```

new_vals_list have his data in this format -> [{Data planning slot 1},{Data planning slot 2}, etc]

But when i try to create multiple planning.slot i get this error :
ValueError: Expected singleton: planning.slot(346, 347)

This is the stacktrace error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1591, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 133, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1618, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1822, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 154, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 697, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 42, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 33, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 466, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_model_create(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 445, in _call_kw_model_create
    return result.id if isinstance(args[0], Mapping) else result.ids
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 5090, in __get__
    raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % record)
ValueError: Expected singleton: planning.slot(350, 351)

The above server error caused the following client error:
null
```

Do you have any idea to resolve this problem ?

Thank's in advance ;)

Comment: The first `if` has a wrong indentation, right?

Comment: Sorry @CZoellner, it was a mistake with the copy of the code on the post.
I have edited it

Comment: Is there a stacktrace to that error? I don't see a mistake in that part of your code.

Comment: Yes i put the error in the post;
This is contextual error :
ValueError: Expected singleton: planning.slot(346, 347)

Comment: That error message is not helpful without more of your code or a stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry, i was expected in that case that stacktrace was not important.
So, i edited my post and add the stacktrace ;)

Comment: Hm, i don't see the mistake and the stacktrace is not helping. How do you call the create?